# linq join on IQueryable IEnumerable

Tags: c#, performance, linq

What would be the best way to join the IEnumerable list with IQueryable.

I already saw this link which talks about it. But I want to know if someone had tried something different. Which wont hinder on performace as i would have huge dataset.

https://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/entity-framework-joining-in-memory-data-with-dbset/

Comment: Pretty much like it says, use `Contains`.  But it really depends on what your in memory `IEnumerable` is.

Comment: But SQL also have some limitaions with IN clause i guess. And for me then it would be big list more than 2000 and would cross it limit.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest batching your in memory data and doing multiple queries.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a large `IEnumerable` and want to join on a database, and the data is too much to embed in a query using `Contains` or something like that extension, I would suggest add a table to your database, uploading the `IEnumerable` into the table, and then doing the join on the database.

But if the `IEnumerable` is much larger than the `IQueryable`, just filter the `IQueryable` as much as possible on the database side and then use `AsEnumerable` to pull it into memory and join there.